# Show that the relation fails to be an equivalence relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, measure-theory

I am trying to show that the following relation is not an equivalence relation.

$x$~$y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if $|x-y|\leq 4$

I know that the relation is not transitive however I am having trouble proving it is not. I have that if $(x,z)\in R$ and if $(z,y) \in R$ where $R$ is the equivalence relation implies $|x-z| \leq 4$  and $|z-y| \leq 4$. To show it is not transitive I would have to show that $|x-z| \leq 4 $ is false. I can come up with one example where it is false (x=4, z=1, y-1) however I feel that coming up with one counter example is not enough.

Is there a more general counter example I could use that doesn't rely on a single example? Or for this problem, would simply showing the above counter example suffice?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with a single counter-example? An example is not sufficient for a proof but a counter-example is fine for a disproof.

Comment: "however I feel that coming up with one counter example is not enough. "  How can that not be enough?  To be transitive it must *always* be true. So it can *never* be false. A single counterexample shows a case were it *not* true and it is *false*.  So that's it.  It *isn't* always true.  That is *ALL* you need!

Comment: I think you mean "to show that it is transitive, I would have to show that $|x-y|\leq 4$." You already have $(x,z)\in R$.

Answer (score 6):

Formally, the statement of transitivity is "*for any* $x,y,z$, if $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$ then $x \sim z$." If you find a set of $x,y,z$ that do not satisfy this, then it is not true for all $x,y,z$, and the relation is not transitive. So your counterexample suffices to prove the relation is not transitive.

P.S. Proving that the relation is *never* transitive is waaayyy stronger than you need, and in this case isn't true. For example, if $x = y = z$ then transitivity holds.

Comment: Awesome! Your P.S. is exactly what I was wondering even though I didn’t state it.

Answer (score 0):

"however I feel that coming up with one counter example is not enough. "  How can that not be enough?  To be transitive it must *always* be true. So it can *never* be false. A single counterexample shows a case were it *not* true and it is *false*.  So that's it.  It *isn't* always true.  That is *ALL* you need!

But if you feel for aesthetic reasons to be more general.

Here's an overkill but *very* general proof (but *way* overkill):

Let $a$ be such $0 < a < 4$.  Let $x\in \mathbb R$.  Let $x_k= x + a*k$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$.

Notice $|x_{k} - x_{k+1}| = a < 4$.

If this relation were transitive then by induction $|x_i - x_j| < 4$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb Z$ in particular $|x_0 - x_n| = na < 4$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

And that is a clear violation of the Archemedian principal.

This is *way* overkll but it does get to the heart of why it's *absurd* to even think it might be transitive.

I suppose another proof that is less overkill and simpler is this:

Let $0 < m$ and $0 < n$ so $0 < m < m+n$.  $|0-m|=m$ and $|(m+n) -m| = n$ and $|0-(m+n)| = m+n$.

If the relation were transitive then we'd have for any $0 < m < 4$ and $0< n < 4$ it would always follow that $m +n < 4$.  That's clearly an absurd conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample suffices: Take $x=0$, $y=4$ and $z=8$.

Then $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$, but not $x\sim z$.